# how to implement netconf + yang c++ server

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

currently I'm implementing netconf server in c++. I found this site:
https://www.appinf.com/docs/poco-2008.2/NetconfUserGuide.html
And thought maybe I'll use poco for the purpose, yet I was unable to find the source code in the github repository, nor after downloading the package from their site. Has poco become comercial or this functionality is now dropped?
My question is can I use poco to implement netconf + yang, is there some other c++ library that solves the problem. Or perhaps should I implement it from scratch.

If yes, then how to proceed? I found also confd with their yang models compiler, but the samples are in C. 
I'd prefer using some existing code written in c++
my current environment is gcc 7.3 with c++17 support and boost 1.64

Comment: Poco is still open source; the NETCONF implementation was never part of Poco, but a commercial product we've built on top of it many years ago. Stopped maintaining it 8 or so years ago and it's no longer available.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for clarifying. I guess I'll try with cond then. However I think that page should be taken down or otherwise marked as obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any open source NETCONF Server projects written in C++, but note the `yuma123` and `netopeer2` open source projects both have NETCONF Server (and Client) implementations written in C.